# Change predefined SMS messages as a reply to being busy

Tags: settings, quick-responses

Can predefined SMS messages that you can select when not being able to pick up the call be somehow configurable? Can we change them somehow?

I know there's the last option of writing a custom SMS message, but I would rather change and localise existing ones to suit my needs and to not repeat the same typing over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit them by going to:

```
Dialer (Phone app) -> Settings -> Quick Responses
```

I have tested it on Android 4.0.4 CyanogenMod 9.

Comment: And guys thanks. I feel like a complete idiot. I was looking at Dialer settings before writing this question, but I was apparently blind or something to not see this option there... :S I'm using vanilla Android 4.2.1 on GNex and this setting is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have an S6 (SM-G920T) with Android 5.1.1 on it and don't have

```
Phone -> Settings -> Quick Responses
```

But based on user40496's post, I was able to find

```
Phone -> Settings -> Call rejection -> Rejection messages
```

where I found the list of messages.

Answer (score -1):

In Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus 
`settings` -> `call` -> `set reject messages`